# Unable to fetch the data from the object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have java script object and i want to fetch the value from object but i am unable to fetch the values from the object.

Here is my javascript object

```
var profile = { '[Profile ID]': 135675302,
  '[Name | Prefix]': '',
  '[Name | First]': 'KK',
  '[Name | Middle]': '',
  '[Name | Last]': 'Test',
  '[Contact Name]': 'KK Test',
  '[Email | Primary]': 'kk@yopmail.com',
  '[Email | Main]': 'kk@yopmail.com',
  '[Address | Primary | Line 1]': '',
  '[Address | Primary | Line 2]': '',
  '[Address | Primary | City]': '',
  '[Address | Primary | State]': '',
  '[Address | Primary | Zip]': '',
  '[Address | Primary | Country]': '',
  '[Address | Main | Line 1]': '',
  '[Address | Main | Line 2]': '',
  '[Address | Main | City]': '',
  '[Address | Main | State]': '',
  '[Address | Main | Zip]': '',
  '[Address | Main | Country]': '',
  '[Phone | Primary]': '',
  '[Organization]': '',
  '*Key Contact': '',
  Facebook: '',
  'Gender Served': [],
  LinkedIn: '',
  'School Size': [],
  'School Website': '',
  'Student Residential Status': [],
  Title: '',
  Twitter: '',
  '[Created Date]': '05/11/2018 11:49:56 AM',
  '[Expiration Date]': '',
  '[Group]': [ 'Members' ],
  '[Last Modified Date]': '05/11/2018 11:49:56 AM',
  '[Member Status]': 'Active',
  '[Member Type]': 'Members',
  '[Username]': 'kk@yopmail.com' }
```

I want to fetch "First name", "Last name" and "Username" from the object.

Any Idea?

Comment: Where is the code you tried using to fetch those values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
var Username = Profile["[Username]"];
var First_name = Profile["[Name | First]"];
var Last_name = Profile["[Name | Last]"];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Darius Buhai. It's working fine for me

Answer (score 2):

Use bracket notation when the property value can't be accessed with dot notation - just put the property value in a string inside the brackets:

```js
var profile = { '[Profile ID]': 135675302,
  '[Name | Prefix]': '',
  '[Name | First]': 'KK',
  '[Name | Middle]': '',
  '[Name | Last]': 'Test',
  '[Contact Name]': 'KK Test',
  '[Email | Primary]': 'kk@yopmail.com',
  '[Email | Main]': 'kk@yopmail.com',
  '[Address | Primary | Line 1]': '',
  '[Address | Primary | Line 2]': '',
  '[Address | Primary | City]': '',
  '[Address | Primary | State]': '',
  '[Address | Primary | Zip]': '',
  '[Address | Primary | Country]': '',
  '[Address | Main | Line 1]': '',
  '[Address | Main | Line 2]': '',
  '[Address | Main | City]': '',
  '[Address | Main | State]': '',
  '[Address | Main | Zip]': '',
  '[Address | Main | Country]': '',
  '[Phone | Primary]': '',
  '[Organization]': '',
  '*Key Contact': '',
  Facebook: '',
  'Gender Served': [],
  LinkedIn: '',
  'School Size': [],
  'School Website': '',
  'Student Residential Status': [],
  Title: '',
  Twitter: '',
  '[Created Date]': '05/11/2018 11:49:56 AM',
  '[Expiration Date]': '',
  '[Group]': [ 'Members' ],
  '[Last Modified Date]': '05/11/2018 11:49:56 AM',
  '[Member Status]': 'Active',
  '[Member Type]': 'Members',
  '[Username]': 'kk@yopmail.com' };
  
  console.log(profile['[Name | First]']);
  console.log(profile['[Name | Last]']);
  console.log(profile['[Username]']);
```

Comment: why answer such questions when so many duplicates are available